# Oracle sql trigger that checks old and new table values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-update

I have a table called Employee that contains several fields, one of them being `current_salary`. I am trying to write a trigger which makes it so the new value of that field can never be smaller than the original one. I have not managed to find a relevant example and i'm new to PL/SQL.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER TR_EMPLOYEE_SAL 
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON EMPLOYEE
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.CURRENT_SALARY > :OLD.CURRENT SALARY THEN
            UPDATE EMPLOYEE
                SET CURRENT_SALLARY = :NEW.CURRENT_SALARY;
        END IF;
    END;
    /
```

My reasoning behind this is the following: It has to check the new value before making changes so therefore i picked "Before". It should compare the existing value to the update one and only change it if the new one is higher than the original. I am obviously missing some basics here so i am in need of some tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
begin
  :new.current_salary := greatest (:old.current_salary, :new.current_salary);
end;
```

Why? Because - in a trigger - you can't `update` table which is just being changed, and that change caused the trigger to fire as you'll get the *mutating table* error.